# How do I pass a specific bean from one JSP file to another only if the button corresponding to that bean was pressed?

Tags: html, jsp, post, jstl, javabeans

I'm trying to pass a bean from one JSP page to another. The source page is the results of a search. The JSP page uses JSTL to print out specific contents of each bean from an ArrayList (returnedPubs) received from my servlet. Within the loop I create a button. This button, when pressed, directs to a details JSP page which will print out all of the contents of that one specific bean. How do I accomplish this? I don't want to query the servlet again for that bean because it's already within that ArrayList.

Here is the source page: (search_results.jsp)

```
<table cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Back" onCLick="history.back()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Publication Number : </th>
        <th>ATA Number : </th>
        <th>Part Number(s) : </th>
        <th>Revision Date : </th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="techPubBean" items="${returnedPubs}">
        <tr>
            <form method="post" action="details.jsp">
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="View Details" />
                </td>
                <td>${techPubBean.getPubNum()}</td>
                <td>${techPubBean.getAtaNum()}</td>
                <td>${techPubBean.getPartNumsTrunc()}</td>
                <td>${techPubBean.getRevDate()}</td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table><br/><br/>
```

and here is the destination page  (details.jsp)

```
<table cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Back" onCLick="history.back()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>ATA Number : </th>
        <td>${techPubBean.getAtaNum()}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Publication Number : </th>
        <td>${techPubBean.getPubNum()}</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table><br/><br/>
```

How do I pass "techPubBean" from search_results.jsp to details.jsp? Everything else works and is in place. Thank you! I'm sure the answer is quite simple.

Kenneth

Comment: You can't pass an object via an HTTP request. You can pass strings. You can put beans in session. You can pass something you can un-marshall back into a custom type. Normally you'd pass an ID and look it up.

Comment: I understand passing via session however that's what I want to avoid here unless there's a way to do it as I've already implemented. Inside the forEach loop I could add that bean to the session but then I'd add every bean to the session which seems totally redundant and unnecessary. I only want to pass along the bean to the other JSP file only if they click that button, so that would mean adding that bean to the session only if they click that button.

Comment: TL;DR. You can either pass an ID, or each field, as a string. Or any other mechanism to reconstitute the object. That's just how HTTP is.

Answer (score 0):

Following Dave Newton comment, the easiest way to handle that would to output the contents on the page and hide them with css/js. Assuming of course that you don't mind having that content  in the source of the page and client side 'trickery' is acceptable.